# Specification of DC motor

Tags: motor, dc

I have a motor, like to use it for a project.  I don't have the specification details of it(volt, Amps, RPM). Can someone help me in this regard?

[image: Image of Motor]

[Image source/Item description](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Original-Mabuchi-12V-21600rpm-RF-370CA-RF-370CA-4035-High-Speed-370-Threaded-Shaft-Motor/32433129909.html?spm=2114.01010208.3.2.MrY2Z6&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_1_116_10065_117_10068_114_115_10069_113_10017_10080_10082_10081_10060_10061_10062_10056_10055_10054_10059_10078_10079_10073_10071_10070_421_420_10052_10053_10050_10051,searchweb201603_7&btsid=e3b7e372-9b60-4fa5-b228-427f269eb163)

Comment: No datasheet, no sale. Simple.

Comment: It is an old motor...i don't have the datasheet....google gives this link, unfortunately it is in Russian...https://ru.aliexpress.com/item/Original-Mabuchi-12V-21600rpm-RF-370CA-RF-370CA-4035-High-Speed-370-Threaded-Shaft-Motor/32433129909.html

Comment: @MattYoung is it possible to find amps when volt and rpm is given.  In this case,  it is 12v and rpm is 21600

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast I got the the volt details. i.e 12v. RPM is 21600.  But they have not given Amps. Is it possible to calculate Amps from volt and RPM.  The translated link is here, https://translate.google.co.in/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=https%3A%2F%2Fru.aliexpress.com%2Fitem%2FOriginal-Mabuchi-12V-21600rpm-RF-370CA-RF-370CA-4035-High-Speed-370-Threaded-Shaft-Motor%2F32433129909.html&edit-text=

Comment: No it's not possible to calculate amps from volts and RPM. The current drawn (for a given motor) will vary depending on voltage, RPM and torque. 21,600 RPM is with zero torque and full voltage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This motor is manufactured by [Mabuchi](http://www.mabuchi-motor.co.jp/en_US/). The part number 'RK-370SD-4045' actually tells you quite lot about it. Referring to the chart below, 'RK' means it has a round (circular) case and carbon brushes. 370 is Mabuchi's designation for motor size and number of armature poles. '4035' means 35 turns of 0.4mm diameter wire on each armature pole. 'SD' means it has anisotropic Ferrite magnets.

[image]

Unfortunately Mabuchi only publishes specs for a small selection of their motors, not every variation. However if you have the specs for one particular wind (wire size and number of turns) it is possible to calculate the specs for other winds. Specs for the [RK-370SD-2870](http://www.rcgroups.com/forums/showatt.php?attachmentid=1130356) are:-

Voltage: range 4.5~9.6V, nominal 7.2V

No-Load: 16500rpm, 0.34A (at 7.2V)

At Stall: 36.3 mNm torque, 8.77A (at 7.2V)

Your motor is identical except for having half as many turns (35 vs 70) of wire which has double the cross-sectional area (0.4mm<sup>2</sup> vs 0.28mm<sup>2</sup>) and therefore 1/4 the resistance and 4 times higher stall current (at the same voltage). With half as many turns the torque constant would be halved, but with 4 times higher stall current the stall torque would be doubled. No-load rpm should be twice as high at the same voltage, as should no-load current (probably a bit more than double due to increased windage and eddy current loss at the higher rpm).

However since apart from the windings both motors have identical construction, their maximum power and rpm ratings should be the same. For the same performance (rpm, torque, power and efficiency) your motor would need half the voltage. So we can estimate the specs of your motor as:-

Voltage: range 2.25~4.8V, nominal 3.6V

No-load: 16500rpm, 0.68A (at 3.6V)

Stall: 36.3mNm torque, 17.5A (at 3.6V)

From these numbers we can derive the motor constants Kv (rpm/Volt), Kt (nM/A), and Rm (resistance) which are used to calculate performance. Mabuchi's performance graph for the RK-370SD-2870 is shown below. Your motor should perform similarly on 3.6V, but with double the current draw. I have marked the changes for your motor in red.

[image]

Note that these calculations (including Mabuchi's own performance graph!) are only theoretical, based on a simple DC motor model. In practice there may be differences due to factors such as brush resistance, timing advance (may be forward, neutral, or reverse), applied voltage etc. To get the *actual* performance on a particular voltage you will have to test a real motor.

Answer (score 1):

Many things can be measured. For example, rotate it with a drill and measurr voltage on contacts-you will know the Kv. Simarly stall it, apply 0.1A and measure torque for Ki. A little more sophisticated setup will yield maximum speed, rotor inertia, almost whatever you need.

Ah, dc resistance and inductance are obvious, aren't they?

Answer (score 0):

Weigh the motor. Look at datasheets for similar weight motors of the same construction. The power is likely to be in the same ball-park.

Measure the diameter of the motor. Look at datasheets for similar diameter motors of the same construction. The speed is likely to be in the same ball-park.

You can estimate the torque from your speed and power estimates above.

Voltage, current, could be anything, but their power product will be in the ball-park of 2 or 3 times the mechanical power, for 3$ motors.

Attach it to a 1.5v AA cell and see whether it turns. It is unlikely to damage either motor or cell, for a 3$ motor. Increase the voltage until it turns at the speed you estimated, or begins to smell or sound bad, at which point you should back off a bit.

Answer (score 0):

It's a "370" size motor according to the photos, which is a very common size of motor.

If you have an unloaded speed at a given voltage, you can roughly calculate the speed constant Kv in RPM-volt. (The figure you get will eb a little lower than the true figure due to the motor's own internal friction)

Convert this to SI units (radians/sec/volt) and invert it : this is the torque constant Kt in N-m/A. (As your Kv figure was a little low, Kt will be a little high - I'd expect 80-90% of this torque)

Measure the DC resistance : you can get the stall current at any voltage from that, and the stall torque from the torque constant.

And for a sanity check, search "370 motor datasheet" and compare the figures you get with a better specified motor wound to run at about the same speed for the same voltage. They should be reasonably close.
(Note, the same basic motor can be rewound for a range of speeds and voltages)